# Hierarchy Query for linked work items in TFS

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2010.
I have many work items (requirements, test cases...)
The work items are linked. I know how to do a query to see the hierarchy of the work items, but when I want to export them to Excel I have just the option to do a flat report.
How can I export a Hierarchy report of work items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only export a flat list or the Tree of Work Item (for the parent/child relation) to Excel.

If you feel that it is important to have this feature included in a future version, you can use [User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com) to add the suggestion. We, as the TFS product team, take these suggestions seriously (and of course the more votes the more likely it will end up in a future version)

Comment: Thanks I will write a request. Is there any work around to do this requirement?